Django Class Based View Failed to Pass a Variable to the Template
I am new to Django and trying to build up a simple catalog site. I inserted some data into the table. So there should be values at primary key = 1
However,  class is empty after passing to the template allclass_detail.html. There should be name and description text above the red line as in the screenshot
Missing text:
,
but now they are missing
Same thing happened to both AllClassDetailView()  and CombatEngravingDetailView()
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import CombatEngraving, ClassEngraving, AllClass, Archetype
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, Http404

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')


class AllClassListView(generic.ListView):
    model = AllClass
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = 'class_list'
    template_name = 'catalog/class_list.html'


class AllClassDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = AllClass

    def all_class_detail_view(request, primary_key):
        try:
            the_class = AllClass.objects.get(pk=primary_key)
        except AllClass.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404('Class does not exist')

        return render(request, 'catalog/allclass_detail.html', context={'class': the_class})


class CombatEngravingListView(generic.ListView):
    model = CombatEngraving
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'combat_engraving_list'
    template_name = 'catalog/combat-engraving.html'


class CombatEngravingDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = CombatEngraving

    def combat_engraving_detail_view(request, primary_key):
        try:
            combat_engraving = CombatEngraving.objects.get(pk=primary_key)
        except CombatEngraving.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404('Combat Engraving does not exist')

        return render(request, 'catalog/combatengraving_detail.html', context={'combat_engraving': combat_engraving})

class_list.html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Class List</h1>
  {% if class_list %}
    <ul>
      {% for class in class_list %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ class.get_absolute_url }}">{{ class.name }}</a>
        &emsp;|{{class.archetype}}|
        &emsp;{{class.first_class_engraving}}&emsp;
        {{class.second_class_engraving}}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% else %}
    <p>There are no class in Trixion.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

allclass_detail.html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ class.name }}</h1>

  <p><strong>Name:</strong> {{ class.name }}</p>
  <p><strong>Archetype:</strong> {{ class.archetype }}</p>
  <p><strong>First Class Engraving:</strong> {{ class.first_class_engraving }}</p>
  <p><strong>Second Class Engraving:</strong> {{ class.second_class_engraving }}</p>
{% endblock %}

models.py
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint
from django.db.models.functions import Lower


class Archetype(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True,help_text="Name of this archetype(e.g. Martial Artist)")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('archetype-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AllClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True,help_text="Name of this class(e.g. Wardancer)")
    archetype = models.ForeignKey('Archetype', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    first_class_engraving = models.ForeignKey('ClassEngraving', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, related_name='first_eng')
    second_class_engraving = models.ForeignKey('ClassEngraving', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, related_name='second_eng')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('class-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                Lower('name'),
                name='genre_name_case_insensitive_unique',
                violation_error_message="Class already exists (case insensitive match)"
            ),
        ]


class CombatEngraving(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('combat-engraving-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class ClassEngraving(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('class-engraving-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

I tried to do the_class = AllClass.objects.get(pk=1) outside of the method. It got correct result printed in the terminal. So I think the method was never called? But I am not sure since I did another beginner project like this and it worked fine.

The problem lies in the way you defined the all_class_detail_view method within the class. Django class-based views, methods such as get, post, etc., are automatically called based on the HTTP request method, but additional methods like all_class_detail_view won't be automatically called unless you explicitly call them.
modify your AllClassDetailView class to ensure that the all_class_detail_view method is called properly:
class AllClassDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = AllClass

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        return self.all_class_detail_view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def all_class_detail_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

also  make sure that your URLs are correctly configured to use the AllClassDetailView view

Thank you! It solved my issue. I replace the last line with return render(request, 'catalog/allclass_detail.html', context={'class': context['object']}) since not sure how to use self.render_to_response lol. Btw I was like 99% sure that this method was not called, but I used almost identical code from my last tutorial project. Now I wonder why it worked last time? It must be called in other way? The link to my last little project: link. If you are willing to further explain it a bit more...
